# Two variables in a macro [SAS]

Tags: variables, macros, sas

So, i want to have a macro that has others macros inside.

Here is the code: `

```
    proc sql NOPRINT ; 
        select id into :l_id separated by ' ' from work.AMOSTRACHU;
        select count(*) into :nr_reg separated by ' ' from tdata.work.AMOSTRACHU;
    quit;

    * check;
    %put l_id=&l_id nr_reg=&nr_reg;


    %macro ciclo_first();
    %do n=1 %to &nr_reg; 
    %let ref=%scan(&l_id,&n);
    %put ref=&ref;


    proc sql; 
    select recetor into : lsus&ref separated by ' ' from tdata.5pct_&ref;
    select count(*) into :nrsus&ref separated by ' ' from tdata.5pct_&ref;
    quit;

    %put lsus&ref=&lsus&ref;
    %put nrsus&ref=&nrsus&ref;

    %MACRO CICLO_PF_SUSref();
%do n=1 %to &nrsus&ref %by 1;
%let sus=%scan(&lsus&ref,&n);
%put sus=&sus;
%LET I = %EVAL(14);
%DO %WHILE (&I<=24);

*my code (depends on &i and &sus)* (works fine alone) 

%LET I = %EVAL(&I+1);

%END;
%END;
%MEND;
%CICLO_PF_SUSref;

%MACRO CICLO_PF_SUS_CSRANK();
%do n=1 %to &nrsus&refm %by 1;
%let sus=%scan(&lsus&ref,&n);
%put sus=&sus;
```

%CICLO_PF_SUSPEITOSrefmsisdn;

```
    %CICLO_PF_SUS_CSRANK;
```

*my code ( just depends on &sus)*/

```
%END;
%MEND;
%CICLO_PF_SUS_CSRANK;

    %end;
    %mend;
    %ciclo_first;`
```

I think the major problem is in this part:

```
%put lsus&ref=&lsus&ref;
    %put nrsus&ref=&nrsus&ref;
```

And the error about that is:

> A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition
>   where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
>          &nrsus&ref

How can i change this in order to work? I understand that it doesn't make all the sense to have something depending on two, like &nrsus&ref.

the first warnings and errors appears here:

```
ref=15
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference LSUS not resolved.
lsus15=&lsus15 WARNING: Apparent symbolic
reference NRSUS not resolved.
nrsus15=&nrsus15 ERROR: Expected semicolon not
found.  The macro will not be compiled.
```

How can i solve this? Have no ideas and it would be really useful to make this macro functional in order to avoid to run this 100 times.

UPDATE [06.08.2015]

I have a table with 100 numbers, that's in

> 'work.amostrachu'.

I created the macro `ciclo_first` in order to run the other 2 macros for this list. because, if i replace manually the `&ref` by the number i want it works fine.

Let's suppose 'work.amostrachu' has:

> ID  1  2  3 (...) till n=100

Then, with this part:

```
 proc sql; 
         select recetor into : lsus&ref separated by ' ' from work.5pct_&ref;
         select count(*) into :nrsus&ref separated by ' ' from work.5pct_&ref;
         quit;
```

I want to get the elements that are on the column 'recetor' of `work.5pct_&ref`.

For `ID=1` i would obtain `lsus1` composed by, for example, 3 numbers (124,564,859)

And, then, the `%MACRO CICLO_PF_SUSref();` will have as input these 3 numbers (that could be 4 or 5 or sometingh else).
(here, i might be calling badly the list of elements i want from '`work.5pct_&ref`).

Then, the output of the previous macro would be the input of this one: `%MACRO CICLO_PF_SUS_CSRANK`. 
And that would be all.

The `%MACRO CICLO_PF_SUSref()` and `%MACRO CICLO_PF_SUS_CSRANK` works ok if i just replace the `&ref` by the id. that's why i tried to create a macro that would run these 2 macros for the initial list. if you have best ideas, i would be thankful.

So, i want something that allows me to run this two macros (`%MACRO CICLO_PF_SUSref()` and `%MACRO CICLO_PF_SUS_CSRANK) for the list i get in the beginning:

```
 proc sql NOPRINT ; 
                select id into :l_id separated by ' ' from work.AMOSTRACHU;
                select count(*) into :nr_reg separated by ' ' from tdata.work.AMOSTRACHU;
            quit;
```

[UPDATE 10.08.2015]

Ok, just read the suggested answers and worked on it.

I have a list, with the identification(numerical) of 100 clients, let's call each client : ref. That's on WORK.AMOSTRACHU.

I wroted the following code and it worked, and will help me explain you what i want:

```
proc sql NOPRINT ; 
    select id into :l_id separated by ' ' from work.AMOSTRACHU;
    select count(*) into :nr_reg separated by ' ' from work.AMOSTRACHU;
quit;

* check;
%put l_id=&l_id nr_reg=&nr_reg;


%macro lista_ent();
%do n=1 %to &nr_reg; 
%put n=&n;
%let ref=%scan(&l_id,&n);
%put ref=&ref;

proc sql; 
select recetor into :listae&ref SEPARATED BY ' ' from work.e5pct_id&ref;
select count(*) into :nre&ref separated by ' ' from work.e5pct_id&ref;
quit;

%end;
%mend;
%lista_ent;
```

Will show you the output for the first 3 cases (of 100, the beggining list in work.amostrachu), it's the results part in SAS:

```
Recetor 
507
723
955
-page break- 
3
-page break-
380
500
675
977
984
-page break-
5
-page break-
200
225
351
488
698
781
927
-page break-
7
```

So, i have the 'values' of the column 'recetor' of the data work.e5pct_id&ref and how many values i have for each ref. (i've showed you results for the first 3 refs, but i have it for the 100).

Now, the first macro:

```
%MACRO CICLO_M_PF_ref();
%local me n i;
%do n=1 %to nre&ref %by 1;
%let me=%scan(listae&ref,&n);
%put me=&me;
%LET I = %EVAL(14);
%DO %WHILE (&I<=24);

proc sql; 
create table work.smthng_&I as
select * from 
work.wtv&I
WHERE A=&me OR B=&me;RUN; 

PROC APPEND
DATA=work.smthng_&I
BASE=work.pf_&me
FORCE;
RUN; 


%LET I = %EVAL(&I+1);

%END;
%END;
%MEND;

%CICLO_M_PF_ref;
```

My all doubts in the & and && are around here.

So, with the data: I have my first ref whose results of column 'recetor' are

```
Recetor 
    507
    723
    955
    -page break- 
    3
```

So, i want to run that code for each one of this values. First for '507', then for '723' and then for '955', and i want to do it for all the refs.

So, when the macro finishes to run my code for this 3, i want the macro to skip to the second ref and then run my code for the values of the column 'recetor' for the second ref: 380,500,675,977 and 984.

i used this code:

```
 proc sql; 
    select recetor into :listae&ref SEPARATED BY ' ' from work.e5pct_id&ref;
    select count(*) into :nre&ref separated by ' ' from work.e5pct_id&ref;
    quit;
```

because each one of the refs have different values and the number of them could be different, just as i showed you. so, this whas to tell the macro to run it  `nre&ref` times and for all values in the list `listae&ref`.

the error is the following:

> ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF
>   condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
>          nre&ref  ERROR: The %TO value of the %DO T loop is invalid. ERROR: The macro CICLO_M_PF_REF will stop executing.

Comment: You generally don't nest macros. I'm having a hard time following, can you include sample data and expected output?

Comment: First i have a list with 100 clients. i want to run the %MACRO CICLO_PF_SUS&ref on them.
Then, on the output of this macro (100 tables) i run the other macro with some queries. 
these two macros work ok out of the "big macro".

Comment: Agree with Reeza. Nesting macro definitions is a bad idea.  It's fine to nest macro invocations. To resolve your error message, try &&nrsus&ref and &&lsus&ref.

Comment: You have `%do ... ;` statement that miss an `%end;` and `%macro ... ;` statement that miss a `%mend;`. If you fix that and properly indent your code and if you then still have errors, I will have a look.

Comment: Dirk Horsten, actually they were'nt missing, i just fogot to paste the end part of the macro. I will update the question, trying to explain better what i want and welcoming new ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Just finished the update. Let me know if you have some doubts.

Comment: You need to call the macros, but you don't define them within each other. Define each macro separately and then write a loop to call them sequentially. I'll add some code later if you or someone else hasn't answered it already.

Comment: What is the dataset WTV&i ? What is the purpose of the PF_xxx datasets? Why not just have the E5PCT and WTV datasets as one table and join them with a simple SQL query?  Why do you need to make hundreds of macro variables and hundreds of tiny datasets?

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite follow your desired output and macro but here are some things I noticed.

1. None of your macros take parameters. If you change your macro to take parameters you can call them individually which may help to stream line your process.

I think you want something like this:

```
%macro def1(param1);
...
%mend;

%macro def2(param2);
...
%mend;

%macro execute();

%do i=1 to 100;
   %def1(param1);
   %def2(param2);
%end;
%mend;
```

This still seems a bit awkward, so if you can explain your process with your data there may be a better way overall.

Comment: Reeza, thank you for the help. I tried to use it, and i wrote an update (10.08.2015)  with more examples in order to explain you better what i want obtain from data.

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of issues you could address, but without test data it is hard to evaluate.

- When trying to show the value for macro variable x&i you need to double up on the prefix &.  So if I=1 and X1 = FRED then &&x&i = FRED.
- When pushing values into macro variables from SQL use the automatic macro variable SQLOBS to get the record count.  No need to run the query again to get the count.
- You cannot select COUNT(*) into multiple macro variables.  SQL will just return one count.
- SAS dataset or variable names cannot start with a digit (tdata.5pct_&ref) or contain periods (tdata.work.AMOSTRACHU).
- Do NOT nest macro definitions. You can nest the calls, but nesting
  the definitions is just going to lead to confusion.

Your actual nested macros do not make much sense. What is this variable I that is introduced?  It appears to be a constant.

Why not just code them as part of the outer macro?  Not much need to make them separate macros if they are only called at one place.

- If you do nest them then make sure to define your local macro variables as local to prevent overwriting the values of macro variables with the same name that might exist in an outer macro scope.  The N looping variable for your %DO loops for example.

First define your subroutine macros.

```
%MACRO CICLO_PF_SUSref(ref_list);
* CICLO_PF_SUSref ;
  %local n sus; 
  %do n=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&ref_list,%str( )));
    %let sus=%scan(&ref_list,&n);
    %put NOTE: &sysmacroname N=&n SUS=&sus;
  %end;
%MEND CICLO_PF_SUSref;

%MACRO CICLO_PF_SUS_CSRANK(ref_list);
* CICLO_PF_SUS_CSRANK ;
  %local n sus ;
  %do n=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&ref_list,%str( )));
    %let sus=%scan(&ref_list,&n);
    %put NOTE: &sysmacroname N=&n SUS=&sus;
    %put NOTE: Call macro named: CICLO_PF_SUSPEITOSrefmsisdn;
  %end;
%MEND CICLO_PF_SUS_CSRANK;
```

Then your main macro.

```
%macro ciclo_first(id_list);
* Start ciclo_first ;
  %local n id ;
  %do n=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&id_list,%str( ))); 
    %let id=%scan(&id_list,&n);
    proc sql noprint; 
        select recetor into : lsus&id separated by ' ' from pct_&id;
    %let nrsus&id = &sqlobs ;
    quit;
    %put NOTE: Current ID=&id ;
    %put NOTE: &&nrsus&id records read from PCT_&ID ;
    %put NOTE: Value List LSUS&id  = &&LSUS&id ;
    %CICLO_PF_SUSref(&&lsus&id);
    %CICLO_PF_SUS_CSRANK(&&lsus&id);
  %end;
* End ciclo_first ;
%mend ciclo_first;
```

Then setup some data and call the main macro.

```
* Setup test data ;
data AMOSTRACHU;
  do id=1 to 2; output; end;
run;
data PCT_1 ;
  do recetor='A','B';
    output;
  end;
run;
data PCT_2 ;
  do recetor='C','D';
    output;
  end;
run;

options mprint;
%ciclo_first(1 2);
```

Comment: Tom, thank you for the help. I tried to use it, and i wrote an update (10.08.2015)  with more examples in order to explain you better what i want obtain from data.

Comment: You still haven't explained WHY you would want to do that.  So the you have list of ids in one file. Then you have list of values for each REF (why are they in different files), but what are you DOING with them? Why do you have such a crazy DO loop?  Looks like you want to code %DO i=14 %TO 24;.  What do 14 and 24 mean?  Since the code inside the %DO loop doesn't reference &I, why are you making 11 copies of the same query?